# turn matrix into long data format

Tags: r, networking, matrix

I want to turn a matrix into a long data.frame edge list of rows to columns like this:

```
  set.seed(666)
  mat <- matrix(sample(0:1,12,replace=TRUE),nrow=3)
  library(bipartite)
  as.data.frame(web2edges(mat, return = TRUE))
```

but i want names of the rows and columns to be in the output for the `row` and `col` columns not the number of the row.

but when i try this i get a duplicate row name error:

```
set.seed(666)
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1,12,replace=TRUE),nrow=3)
colnames(mat) <- letters[1:4]
rownames(mat) <- letters[5:7] 
library(bipartite)
as.data.frame(web2edges(mat, return = TRUE))
```

> Error in data.frame(row = c("1", "3", "3", "1", "2"), col = c("4", "4",  : 
>     duplicate row.names: g, e

Is there another easy way this can be achieved without using `web2edges`?

Comment: Maybe set the rownames of the `web2edges()` result to NULL, then convert to a data.frame? Or just do `as.data.frame.table(mat)` straight up and then subset.

Comment: i like the table and subset option, @thelatemail if you want to answer I'd happily accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from n x m matrix to long matrix in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367922/convert-from-n-x-m-matrix-to-long-matrix-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Data frames, unlike matrices, cannot have duplicate row names.  So rather than changing the row and column names before `web2edges`, you will have to do it afterwards.

```
set.seed(666)
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1,12,replace=TRUE),nrow=3)
library(bipartite)

#data frame with numerical values in `row` and `col` columns:
ndf <- as.data.frame(web2edges(mat, return = TRUE))

#converting `row` and `col` columns to factors:
ndf$col <- factor(ndf$col, levels = 4:7, labels = letters[1:4])
ndf$row <- factor(ndf$row, levels = 1:3, labels = letters[5:7])

> ndf
  row col edge.weights
1   e   a            1
2   g   a            1
3   g   b            1
4   e   c            1
5   f   d            1
```