# melting matrices with logical values

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a matrix with pairwise comparisons, of which the upper triangle and diagonal was set to `NA`.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(NA,1,2), b=c(NA,NA,3), c=c(NA,NA,NA))
row.names(df) <- names(df)
```

[I want to transform the matrix to long format, for which the standard procedure is to use reshape2's `melt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367922/convert-from-n-x-m-matrix-to-long-matrix-in-r), followed by `na.omit`, so my desired output would be:

```
Var1 Var2 Value
a     b   1
a     c   2
b     c   3
```

However, `df$c` is all NA and thus logical, and will be used as a non-measured variable by `melt`.
The output of `melt(df)` is therefore not what i am looking for.

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df)
```

How can I prevent melt from using `df$c` as id variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have other answers already, this *can* be achieved with `reshape2` and `melt`, if the appropriate function is called. In this case you don't want `reshape2:::melt.data.frame` but rather `reshape2:::melt.matrix` to be applied. So, try:

```
melt(as.matrix(df), na.rm=TRUE)
#  Var1 Var2 value
#2    b    a     1
#3    c    a     2
#6    c    b     3
```

If you then take a look at `?reshape2:::melt.data.frame` you will see the statement:

> This code is conceptually similar to ‘as.data.frame.table’

which means you could also use the somewhat more convoluted:

```
na.omit(as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(df), responseName="value"))
#  Var1 Var2 value
#2    b    a     1
#3    c    a     2
#6    c    b     3
```

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to convert the rownames to column and then convert to long format. A way to do it in `tidyverse` would be,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(var, val, -1) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(val))


#  rowname var val
#1       b   a   1
#2       c   a   2
#3       c   b   3
```

As @Humpelstielzche mentions in comments, there is a `na.rm` argument in gather so we can omit the last filtering, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 rownames_to_column() %>% 
 gather(var, val, -1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: you can just specifiy `na.rm = T` inside gather.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `row` and `col` to get row names and column names respectively and then filter the `NA` values.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col = colnames(df)[col(df)], row = rownames(df)[row(df)], 
                  value = unlist(df), row.names = NULL)

df1[!is.na(df1$value), ]

#  col row value
#2   a   b     1
#3   a   c     2
#6   b   c     3
```